# How to increase the resolution of this figure?

Tags: graphics3d

I am saving this image using "save graphics as" command but the image quality is poor after saving. How can i improve the resolution of this image. [image]

After zooming the image pixels start distorting. I also wanted to get rid of black points on the corner of edges. Is there any nicer way to save in good resolution? I heard that SVG graphics are very pretty. Is that possible to save in SVG graphics?

My code is

```
SetOptions[{SphericalPlot3D, ParametricPlot3D}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotPoints -> 200];
{fun = r {Sin[t], -Cos[t], 0}};
p0 = SphericalPlot3D[{20, 21}, {θ, 0, Pi/2}, {ϕ, -Pi, Pi},
    PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[RGBColor[0.0863, 0.1216, 0.0784], Opacity[1], 
     Specularity[White, 30]]];
p1 = ParametricPlot3D[fun, {r, 0, 8}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[White, Opacity[1], 
     Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[1]}}, Specularity[]]];
p2 = ParametricPlot3D[fun, {r, 8, 14}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[RGBColor[0.8392, 0.8392, 0.8392], Opacity[1], 
     Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[1]}}, Specularity[]]];
p3 = ParametricPlot3D[fun, {r, 14, 21}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> 
    Directive[RGBColor[0.9608, 0.9490, 0.5216], Opacity[1], 
     Lighting -> {{"Ambient", GrayLevel[1]}}, Specularity[]]];
Show[p0, p1, p2, p3, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
 DisplayFunction :> Identity, ImageSize -> {360., 309.556}, 
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-21., 20.9569}, {-20.9892, 20.9892}, {0., 21.}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}, 
 ViewPoint -> {2.81505, 0.317116, -1.85065}, 
 ViewVertical -> {0.451886, -0.726318, -1.03575}]
```

Comment: It is evident from your figure that antialiasing is switched off in your preferences. Try to switch it on.

Comment: `Export[filename, graphics, ImageSize -> {8000,6000}]` or similar (with a big ImageSize) may do what you want.

Comment: Or you could try this `Export["filename.jpg", graphics, ImageResolution -> 600]`

Comment: There is no option of "Save selection As " command in my mathematica. But i got the good images after using this command Export["filename.jpg", graphics, ImageResolution -> 600]
Thanks to @Hubble07

Answer (score 2):

SVG graphics are good because they are not raster images and do not have pixels they have paths. When you zoom in on a vector image, like a SVG, your computer can generate new pixel information based on the vector paths. You have two options I'm aware of, you can do what I normally do and save as a PDF, which saves as a vector like SVG, or you can increase the image size and then when you save as a raster image (.GIF,.PNG,.JPEG), you will have a higher resolution image. PDF is a better option because a vector image often has a smaller file size than a high resolution photo, and also because you can zoom indefinitely--which is never the case with a raster image.

Make sure to delete the "Out[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvhsc.png)=" before saving as PDF, for some reason it doesn't crop it out.

Also, right clicking on the right bracket is a nice shortcut for saving graphics.[image]